# Ubuntu 17.10 - Zesty errors during update

Tags: 17.10, repository

Tonight I upgraded my Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 to fix the "zesty errors" while updating my computer. After I upgraded my computer I still keep receiving the error messages.

Output of `apt-get update` (Error lines):

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com wheezy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
E: The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com wheezy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What I understand is that zesty is not supported anymore. Does this mean I can remove all zesty lines in: Software & updates --> Other software??
Example: [Other software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWefE.png)

```
jowi@jowi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Comment: Did you reboot after upgrading?